# I do not want overlapping in my 2 column un-ordered list

Tags: css

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/EebVF/252/)

how can I have the `li` tags evenly spaced out so it can handle varied lenght of names

for example `<li>1dddddddddddddddddddddd</li>` overlaps on `<li>6</li>`, I want them to be spaced

**EDIT1** adding code

```
<ul class='cols2'>
    <li>1dddddddddddddddddddddd</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT2** the view I would expect to achieve

```
1dddddddddddddddddddddd     6
2                           7
3                           8
4                           9
5                           10
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: An image of how you **expect** this to look would also be useful.

Comment: Just remove the width

Answer (score 1):

You may use flex

```css
.cols2{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class='cols2'>
    <li>1dddddddddddddddddddddd</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```